# why the StringBuffer does not change?

Tags: java, stringbuffer

```
public class Test1{
public static void main(String[] args){
    StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer("abcde");
    reverseString(s);
    System.out.println(s);
}
public static int reverseString(StringBuffer s){
    StringBuffer s1=new StringBuffer("");
    int length=s.length();
    for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--){
        s1.append(s.charAt(i));

    }
    s=s1;
    return 1;
}
```

}

I want change the StringBuffer.In the method,s="edcba",but i run the class,the result is ”abcde".Why?

Comment: Why not just use `StringBuffer.reverse()`?

Comment: In Java 5.0 (2004) it recommends you use `StringBuilder` for 99% of cases.  This is one of them.

Comment: Oh,it is a question of a interview.Thanks for your help

Comment: Please don't use a StringBuffer when you can use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JAVA, variables are always passed by val and what you're attempting to do, the variable needs to be passed by ref.  In order to do what you want to do, the reference can't change, but the properties of the object CAN.

```
public static int reverseString(StringBuffer s){ 
    StringBuffer s1=new StringBuffer(""); 
    int length=s.length(); 
    for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--){ 
        s1.append(s.charAt(i)); 

    } 
    s.replace(0, length, s1.toString()); 
    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: I am just a fresh man.Thanks!Your favor is helpful, and solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You only change the StringBuilder s1 in the reverseString function. So the s StringBuilder  in the main will be the same. Instead you should return s1 when you are done.

```
public class Test1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer("abcde");
        StringBuffer s1 = reverseString(s);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
    public static StringBuffer reverseString(StringBuffer s){
        StringBuffer s1 =new StringBuffer("");
        int length=s.length();
        for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--){
            s1.append(s.charAt(i)); 
        }
        return s1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `s1` is a `StringBuffer` but `return s1` needs to be a String. Perhaps you meant `StringBuffer`

Comment: This will be avoiding the question rather than answering it.. Check Chris Gessler's post for the answer.

Comment: Thanks,it is a question of a interview,the return value should be int.